# Asserting in Cypress - 'Assert expected <span.text-xogo-grey-light.ml-2> to have value '0' but the value is ' '

Tags: html, cypress

[Check Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRdmZ.png)

I am trying to assert an element with the value '0' in it but every time I try to use my code I get an error saying that there were no '0' found instead the value was ''.

The HTML element is this:

```html
<span class="text-xogo-grey-light ml-2">0</span>
```

My code is this:

```
cy.get('span[class="text-xogo-grey-light ml-2"]').should('have.value','0')
```

I tried using this:

```
cy.get('span[class="text-xogo-grey-light ml-2"]').should('have.value',0)
```

But did not work. The only thing that worked for me is this:

```
cy.get('span[class="text-xogo-grey-light ml-2"]').should('have.value', '')
```

Here is the full HTML element:

```html
<div class="flex-1 text-lg flex flex-col justify-center"><div>
<span class="text-xfxl">LIBRARY</span> 
<span class="text-xogo-grey-light ml-2">1</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Spans don't have a "value", are you trying to assert on the _text content_?

Comment: But the page I am working on has, the span class that displays the values of how many items there are on that specific page. Please check the updated question thanks.

Comment: The point remains. You might consider the text to be a value, but from an HTML attribute perspective it's not.

Comment: So how do you propose I assert the value there?

Comment: I already said - that's the text content.

Comment: Okay So how do you propose that I assert the text contents there? The text contents of that div change accordingly with the images/videos added or removed.

Comment: I propose you look up for example "Cypress assert text content" in a search engine of your choice. _"The text contents of that div change"_ - yes? That's exactly the point, isn't it, that's why you want to assert that it's currently showing the _right_ text.

Comment: Yes, that is the point but when it comes to 0 I am unable to assert it, only and only when it becomes 0 I am unable to do it. That is why I raised this question. I am trying to have an assertion when it is zero '0'.

Comment: Definitely recommend learning more about HTML attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are nearly there. `have.value` asserts the value attribute in your html whereas you are trying to assert the inner text, so `have.text` should do the job for you.

```js
cy.get('span[class="text-xogo-grey-light ml-2"]').should('have.text', '1')
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as you used in your previous question

```js
cy.get('.font-semibold')
  .should('have.text', '\n        Got questions? Checkout our Quick Start Guide to see how it all works\n      ')
```

You seem to have no trouble with the concept, why now?